# How to mask/clip video with SVG path?

Tags: html, css, svg

I watched this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTKnhVTeN4w
(If you don't want to watch it I left the whole code below, it's short, so you can check it).

It's great and works fine:
[text element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hja3E.png)

I wanted to replace text element with my own path element.
And here what I got:
[my path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvJdR.png)

It's deer antlers on the screen. The full image looks this way:
https://svgshare.com/s/_7d
You can check its code, there is a lot of stuff that I cut off and keep just 1 path to make it simpler.

I wanted to freely place and position my svg to make deer's head visible, but when I added and set viewBox everything ruining:
[added viewBox to make deer visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahdZe.jpg)

How can I clip my video with my own svg by this method? I can't use clip-path CSS property, because I need to support IE11. Also you can suggest other methods compatible with IE11 for clipping video with svg if you know.

Full code:

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 88px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

svg rect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    fill: white;
    mask: url(#mask);
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1254 1598">
            <defs>
                <mask id="mask">
                    <rect/>
                    <!-- <text fill="red" x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">
                        I love SVG
                    </text> -->
                    <!-- This is deer -->
                    <path d="M356 1304c.553 17.882 25.394 152.989 102 209 96.015 70.202 249.088 61.648 261 61 21.416-1.166 46-28 46-28s80.21-17.15 54-121c.077-53.67-17.898-103.433 5.46-149.087 13.964-11.32 18.562-34.142 18.562-34.142s111.349 10.111 214.568-15.587c37.431 4.217 134.883 21.66 152.944-48.987 8.586-.025 15.386-8.377 11.466-23.197 4.923-6.789 23.034-21.196 11.55-42.861-3.595-5.818-12.913-17.224-21.531-18.556-7.913-5.252-48.452-39.276-66.82-46.018-18.433-16.464-95.331-76.782-106.17-86.098-10.84-9.317-93.144-94.502-113.595-101.686-8.52-9.876-61.03-75.46-73.502-79.418 10.169-3.878 68.57-23.648 90.578-72.738 24.723-21.75 54.389-59.72 37.865-138.797-2.745-7.731-8.377-11.596-8.91 5.195-.531 16.792-17.15 66.736-21.53 76.45-3.383-16.542-10.405-79.666-50.487-80.16-10.804-.878-8.333 7.336-.742 10.39 7.591 3.055 19.859 11.617 20.788 35.628.93 24.01 6.046 62.592-4.454 68.285-10.5 5.692-90.343 37.08-125.474 40.08-34.308-7.896-94.291-27.462-94.291-27.462s81.952-57.316 72.017-101.686c-3.388-.938-5.654 13.62-15.591 20.04-9.937 6.421-86.778 60.9-98.746 62.347-9.575-11.45-33.64-39.446-31.182-55.667 6.065-5.11 25.32-28.814 40.834-66.058 18.268-43.85 31.68-102.99 17.077-121.725-9.892 12.15-19.039 45.181-23.759 57.893-4.72 12.712-29.43 81.247-51.229 92.037-25.946 18.853-70.91 8.31-89.836-3.711 2.25-26.557 12.374-96.033 14.849-113.561 2.475-17.528 14.845-80.055 15.591-109.108 3.98-26.53 11.713-110.97 13.364-118.014 3.256-9.18 11.475-44.01 7.425-65.316-1.046-20.36-.109-37.698-7.425-37.111-7.315.587-6.318 30.682-8.909 42.307-2.591 11.625-17.362 61.012-25.243 91.294-7.881 30.282-19.117 181.116-54.941 181.103-34.294-10.758-39.987-40.853-42.32-60.862 4.268-30.926 5.197-68.285 5.197-68.285s9.764-166.818 11.137-189.269c5.799-28.478 47.517-112.818 47.517-112.818S494 4.252 479.965 10.415c-3.96 6.154-7.425 12.618-7.425 12.618s-7.527-14.084-18.56-2.97c-3.404 9.744-7.224 14.943-12.622 23.752-5.399 8.81-22.209 49.534-32.668 61.605-10.46 12.071-27.867 35.39-36.38 35.627-8.514.236-34.024-3.234-42.32-20.04-8.296-16.806-11.879-24.494-11.879-24.494s-10.207-4.162-8.91 5.196c1.299 9.357 1.183 19.325 11.138 25.236-16.942-7.801-47.901-36.606-51.972-34.885-4.07 1.72-23.319 34.877 70.533 75.707 6.153 4.948 27.985 35.66 23.758 67.543-9.29 28.684-16.848 31.685-19.304 37.111-2.455 5.426-3.356 21.599-14.106 27.463-10.75 5.864-30.694 17.565-50.487-4.454-19.792-22.019-23.974-28.719-25.243-37.853-1.269-9.135-16.959-102.409-6.682-135.828s36.126-69.617 28.213-80.16c-12.655 2.373-27.649 26.95-33.41 34.142-5.761 7.192-15.59 15.452-41.577 97.974-9.445 33.315-20.993 74.685-43.062 92.778-23.934 10.52-61.665 26.983-80.927 26.72-19.261-.262-45.29-13.36-45.29-13.36l-8.166 11.876 6.682 8.907s36.442 21.703 65.335 23.009c29.439 4.374 53.577 20.323 61.623 40.08 8.047 19.758 8.91 17.072 8.91 17.072s35.984 62.058-31.183 84.614c-56.425 12.222-57.168-1.485-57.168-1.485s-36.88-92.954-40.835-89.81c-11.69 9.912 6.544 71.818 6.682 96.49-.532 39.073-31.738 51.598-25.986 77.934 4.575 9.76 16.965-16.74 42.32-14.844 25.355 1.894 53.713 2.718 115.08-8.165 73.895 4.643 167.617 5.789 199.718 31.174 32.1 25.384 53.806 40.928 60.88 44.533 7.679 13.977 7.157 69.194 146.263 121.725 22.063 17.441 37.865 37.854 37.865 37.854l-68.305-15.587s-62.93-47.79-92.806-25.977c-26.237-13.748-64.926-35.539-72.018-5.196 12.136 38.803 16.022 76.517 60.88 122.467 44.86 45.95 69.473 80.073 82.412 84.614-13.205 26.171-85.418 228.277-113.594 282.047-28.176 53.77-60.618 60.53-59.372 100.825z" />
                </mask>
            </defs>
            <rect/>
        </svg>

        <video autoplay muted loop playsinline preload>
            <source src="video/bg.mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think there are any good answers for IE11.

Comment: I thought like you and that's why I chose this method, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I almost solved my problem, but faced new one - I need background-image around mask. I think it's impossible by using this method because mask is surrounded by rect element which cannot have background-image. Do you agree with that? If you didn't understand let me know I'll show you screenshots.

Comment: A rect can contain a pattern and the pattern can contain an image.